# Уникальный ключ. Алгоритм

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть строка вида `H-003001020000` длиной до 20 символов. Необходимо получить уникальное значение для каждой строки из 9 цифр. Что-то вроде хеша, но без вероятности коллизий. Если строка короче, можно дополнить пробелами.

На примере. 
На входе строка `H-003001020000`. На выходе некий ключ - `191922678`.
На входе строка `H-003001030000`. На выходе некий ключ - `566675554`.
Опять на входе строка `H-003001020000`. На выходе ключ - `191922678`.
Уникальность критична.

Заранее спасибо за любые наводки.

**upd1**:
Про `ora_hash` думал. Перефразирую.

```
create table ex1 (key varchar2(20)); 
insert into ex1 ('Y-000011'); 
insert into ex1 ('Y-000012'); 


create table ex2 (key varchar2(20)); 
insert into ex2 ('Y-000012');
```

Есть запрос

```
select * from ex1 left join ex2 using (key);
```

Есть еще таблица

```
create table ex3 (key number(9));
```

Необходимо связать выборку из первых двух с ex3 и добавить/обновить данные в ex3 по ключу. Надеюсь, понятно выразился. Тут очень неудобно комментировать. Архитектура дана как есть.

**upd2**: Пока видится только создание смежной таблицы и формирование ключа для ex3 последовательностью. Думаю над другими вариантами.

Comment: Ключ в 9 символов критичен? или можно больше?

Comment: А ключ то какой длины. Вы же понимаете, что если ключ в байтах короче строки, то гарантированно без коллизий невозможно, ибо не хватит информационной емкости ключа. Тем более что в строке у вас буквы, а это минимум 26+10 значений на разряд, а в цифрах только 10 значений на разряд. А так, ora_hash и запоминание в некой таблице значений которые были. Ну или тупо строка - id :)

Comment: Да. Это ограничение не изменить.

Comment: Тогда вам никак не уйти от вероятностных коллизий. Смиритесь

Comment: Про ora_hash думал. Перефразирую.

Comment: А чем вызвано такое ограничение. Строго 9 цифр. Возможно стоит еще раз подумать над архитектурой?

Comment: Пока видится только создание смежной таблицы и формирование ключа для ex3 последовательностью. Думаю над другими вариантами.

Comment: @Pivoter внизу под вопросом, есть ссылочка "править". Вносите значимые сведения в вопрос используя ее.

Comment: так вы пытаетесь ручками реализовать хэш-индекс? ну так должны быть стандартные инструменты для этого (с oracle не работал, не скажу точно). В любом случае, любая субд при работе с хэш-индексом ищет сначала по хэшу, а потом проверяет сами записи на соответствие. Профит достигается за счет того, что коллизий не так уж и много, поэтому проверять записи на соответствие приходится не так уж и много, что в итоге будет быстрее чем проверять все подряд. Т.е. хэш без коллизий и не нужен

Comment: @Pivoter И почему бы просто не добавить в ex1 тупо колонку id, если конечно каждая строка в это таблице уникальна

Comment: Ни в одну из таблиц я не могу ничего добавить. Изначальные требования. В ex1, ex2 - key уникально. В ex3 формируется уже мной. Тоже нужен уникальный. Про хеш-индекс почитаю, может быть поможет.

Comment: @Pivoter А чем вам не нравится добавление всей строки к себе в таблицу (ну или в другую). Все равно другие решения невозможны ибо как сказано выше, "у числа не хватит информационной емкости для уникального обозначения строки"

Comment: @Mike Да, так и поступлю. Просто хотел убедиться, что действительно невозможно по-другому. Вдруг мой мозг меня обманывает =)

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.